# Export certain DataGridView columns to Text File (.inp) format

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files

I want to export my datagridview to text file but not all 7 columns.

I want to export only 3 columns separated with "**;**".

For example: Column1 Value;column2 value;column value

Comment: So you're looking for a delimited text file,  What is your DataGrid bound to because generally this type of thing is fair simpler and robust when done on the underlying data collection.  Check for 3rd party tools as well (nugets), someone quite possibly done the heavy lifting for you already

Comment: It seems redundant to repeat Column1, Column2, Column3 in every line of the file. Make the column headings the first row and follow with the values of each row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about perfect performance, you can do it like this:

```
Dim x,y as integer
Dim sLine as string 

FileOpen(1, "C:\sample\file.csv", OpenMode.Output) ' change to your path

For y = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    sLine = ";"
    For x = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count-1
        if x=1 OrElse x=3 OrElse x=5 then
            sLine = sLine & DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString & ";"
        End if
    Next x
    PrintLine(1, sLine)
Next y

FileClose(1)
```

The line: x=1 OrElse x=3 OrElse x=5, are the columns numbers that you want, just adjust. You can also use an array like Dim iColsIWant as Integer = {1,3,5} and use them as X variable.
If you want to include the headers of the datagridview, after FileOpen you can write for example:

```
PrintLine (1,";Name;Date;Value;")
```